# как реализовать авто запуск программы с флешки на win7 и выше?

Tags: windows, взлом, flash-память

Добрый день, интересует запуск *.exe с флешки автоматически при установке в гнездо флешки, на 7 винде это можно реализовать перепрошивкой флешки , накидайте пожалуйста информации или объясните как реализовать, только добрые побуждения)

Comment: *на 7 винде это можно реализовать перепрошивкой флешки* Сказки. Если настройки ОС запрещают автозапуск, никакая перепрошивка не поможет.

Comment: @Akina не соглашусь с вами, флешку можно перепрошить как совместимое устройство (например клавиатура) и отправить команды на открытие кмд и запуск файла, например так , я не считаю что это большая проблема(, это просто пример )

Comment: @Akina [gitgub](https://github.com/brandonlw/Psychson) вот наковырял чуть чуть

Comment: Это ты сейчас про `autorun.inf` спрашиваешь?